# Track dialog events in composer dialogs

Tags: botframework, chatbot, bot-framework-composer

We have a mixed composer project. The Composer dialogs were created with Composer, but the project is programmed with C#. The logging of the Luis results works perfectly. However, we don't get any dialog events (start, end) logged in AppInsights. Does anyone have any idea why this might be.
Here is the code:

```
var ausstiegXXDialogResource = resourceExplorer.GetResource("Ausstieg_XX_Dialog.dialog");
var ausstiegXXDialog = resourceExplorer.LoadType<AdaptiveDialog>(ausstiegXXDialogResource);

// Log the data to AppInsights with _telemetryClient

ausstiegXXDialog.TelemetryClient = this._telemetryClient;

AddDialog(ausstiegXXDialog);
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "mixed composer" project?

Comment: Yes, it is a C#-project. In a subfolder, there are all Composer dialogs which were allocated as you can see above. The root dialog is a C#-Dialog, not a composer dialog. It is a project with C# code and composer dialogs.

Comment: Have you had a chance to review this code first C# bot sample [21.corebot-app-insights](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/21.corebot-app-insights)? This bot shows how to use Application insights to monitor your bot. I tested from my local machine and telemetry was logged successfully in app insights.

Comment: Documentation for adding telemetry to a code-first bot found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-telemetry?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp